# What is wrong with the below code in which I am trying to manipulate a string and produce the output using copy algorithm?

Tags: vector, stl, copy

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class charVector
{
    vector<char> cv;
    public:
    //Function to initialize vector by characters in a string
    void initializeVector(string);
    //Function to duplicate a vector at its back
    void dupVector();
    //Function to add reverse of a vector at its back
    void dupRevVector();
    void print();
};
```

this is the part of the code where I am facing the problem:-

```
#include<algorithm>
#define all(c) c.begin(),c.end()
#define rall(c) c.rbegin(),c.rend()
void charVector::initializeVector(string s)
{
    for(int i=0;i<s.size();i++) {
    cv.push_back(s[i]);}
}
void charVector::dupVector()
{
    int x;
    x=cv.size();
    cv.resize(2*cv.size());
    copy(all(cv),cv.end()-x);
}
void charVector::dupRevVector()
{
    int x;
    x=cv.size();
    cv.resize(2*cv.size());
    //copy(cv.rbegin(),cv.rend(),cv.end()-x);
    copy(rall(cv),cv.end()-x);
}
void charVector::print()
{
    for(typeof(cv.begin()) i=cv.begin();i!=cv.end();i++)
    {
        cout<<*i;
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
```

upto here is the not working code

```
int main()
{
    charVector ch1,ch2;
    string s1,s2;
    cin>>s1>>s2;
    ch1.initializeVector(s1);
    ch2.initializeVector(s2);  
    ch1.dupVector();
    ch2.dupRevVector();
    ch1.print();
    cout<<endl;
    ch2.print();
    cout<<endl;
}
```

when the input is abc and def the output should be abcabc and deffed but the output is abcabc and def???

thank you in advance

Comment: `copy(all(cv),cv.end()-x);` Here, `all(cv)` runs over the expanded, double-sized vector, not just the first half that contains valid data. As a result, your program exhibits undefined behavior by way of a buffer overrun.

Comment: the part of copy(all(cv),cv.end()-x); is working but the part where the  copy(rall(cv),cv.end()-x); is not working

Comment: No, `copy(all(cv),cv.end()-x)` is not working. It's exhibiting undefined behavior. "Seems to work" is one possible manifestation of undefined behavior. Anyway, `copy(rall(cv),cv.end()-x);` has the same problem - it copies the second, empty half over itself, and then the first, non-empty half is written out of bounds.